# bash condition within Pipenv Pipfile script

Tags: python, bash, scripting, pipenv

I have a Pipfile with such script

```
[script]
tests = "pytest --cov-fail-under=40 tests/"
```

I wan to make the **cov-fail-under** parameter value depend on a env var. Out of the Pipfile script, the following command does the job:

```
pytest --cov-fail-under=$( case $VARin true ) echo 40 ;; * ) echo 80 ;; esac ) tests/
```

But when executed with the `pipenv run tests` the bash condition is shown as a string producing the following error:

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: argument --cov-fail-under: invalid validate_fail_under value: '$('
```

Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spawn a shell with `sh -c`:

*Pipfile*

```
[scripts]
tests = "sh -c '[ \"${VAR}\" = \"true\" ] && mincov=40 ; pytest --cov-fail-under=\"${mincov:-80}\" tests'"
```

Comment: By the way the suggested approach does not work within pipenv's scripts 
    `ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
    pytest: error: argument --cov-fail-under: invalid validate_fail_under value: '${MIN_COVERAGE:-40}'`

Comment: did you use single quotes? or was is it just the error message? If so, can you try double quotes? I have to install pipenv to test it, will do.